# Why JSON allows only string to be a key?

Tags: javascript, json, ecma262

Why does JSON only allow a `string` to be a key of a pair? Why not other types such as `null`, `number`, `bool`, `object`, `array`? Considering JSON is tightly related with JavaScript, could I conclude the reason from JavaScript specification (ECMA-262)? I'm totally a newbie to JavaScript, could you help me to point it out.

Comment: I wouldn't say JSON is part of JavaScript. Its data structures are based on object and array literal notation found in JavaScript, but its existence is independent of ECMA-262.

Answer (score 13):

The JSON format is deliberately based on a subset of JavaScript object literal syntax and array literal syntax, and JavaScript objects can only have strings as keys - thus JSON keys are strings too. (OK, you can sort of use numbers as JavaScript object keys, but really they get converted to strings.)

Note that the point of JSON is that it is a string representation of data to allow easy exchange between programs written in different languages running on different machines in different environments. If you wanted to use an object as a key then that object would in turn have to be somehow represented as a string for transmission, but then the receiving language would need to be able to use objects as keys and that would mean you'd need a limited subset of JSON for those languages which would just be a mess.

> "Considering JSON is a part of JavaScript"

No, it isn't. Newer browsers provide methods for creating and parsing JSON, but they're not part of the language as such except that JSON is a string format and JavaScript can do strings. JSON is *always* a string representation - it has to be parsed to create an object for use within JavaScript (or other languages) and once that happens JavaScript (or the other languages) treat the resulting object the same as any other object.

(Note also that a particular bit of JSON doesn't necessarily have any keys at all: it could just be an array, like `'["one","two","three"]'`.)

Comment: String is almost directly supported in different languages, but object must be a customized. We have to do something to deal with object from value, that could be the same way for key. If we did limited key could only be a string because of crossing language exchanging easiness, then that was to say value was limited like that too. I'd rather consider it vice in JavaScript.

Comment: JSON is designed for exchange of _data_. If your application's data is so complicated that you can't find a way to represent it using just string-based key-names then I'd suggest that you're making things too hard for yourself. If you feel you must have objects as keys then you can do that in JSON by including a (nested) `keys` object that maps string-based property names to objects so those objects become sort of "virtual keys". The answer to your original question, "Why only strings?" is because that's all that is needed for JSON's purpose and that's what the original designer settled on.

Answer (score 6):

Main reason according to the discoverer of `JSON` representation is,

> while parsing **JSON** data, there is a chance/possibility that, **key**
>   you are using to refer a **value** might be a  **reserved word** in your
>   parsing language.

Refer this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C-JoyNuQJs) by Douglas Crockford, who is the discoverer of **JSON** representation.

**Example :**

```
{ 
    id: 1234, 
    name: "foo", 
    do: "somthing"
}
```

Since **JSON** is a cross language compatibility, We can use this data set in many languages. But, the word `do` is a keyword in `Javascript`. It will end up in syntax error while parsing.

Comment: although most programming languages will not use numbers as keys, but numbers are not allowed either.

Answer (score -4):

Because that is the way the specification was written.

Comment: Then why it's written so. Everything comes with a reason.

Comment: @paladin_t -- Not necessarily.  Sometimes it's just the preference of the writer.

Comment: @Hot Licks, that's reasonable.

Comment: @paladin_t -- Not necessarily -- many writers are quite unreasonable. ;)

Comment: -- insert anti joke chiken meme -- :-)

Comment: @Hot Licks but even if it were merely the writer's preference, few people (engineers especially) make **purely** arbitrary decisions.

Comment: So say we all! ;)