# Dynamic JSON struct, API result golang

Tags: json, api, http, parsing, go

I have to make two HTTP API calls in GoLang, the first API call returns this json response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    "id": "24",
    "folderid": "4248"
  }
}
```

My json struct for first response is setup like this:

```
type One struct {
    Status int    `json:"status"`
    Msg    string `json:"msg"`
    Result struct {
        ID       string `json:"id"`
        Folderid string `json:"folderid"`
    } `json:"result"`
}
```

The  second call is where the problem is. As you can see the first API call returns a result -> id. This ID should be the name for the beginning of my second struct, but I can't seem how to make it dynamic or put a result as my structure name. This ID (24) will always change based on the first API call. I have no way currently to parse the second call's JSON and setup my struct. On the second API call I want to access the remoteurl/status.

Second call result (I can not parse):

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    24: ** THIS IS DYNAMIC** {
      "id": 24,
      "remoteurl": "http://proof.ovh.net/files/100Mio.dat",
      "status": "new",
      "bytes_loaded": null,
      "bytes_total": null,
      "folderid": "4248",
      "added": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "last_update": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "extid": false,
      "url": false
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to setup my struct or go about this. I am a new programmer and go and have worked on this for 4 days. And decided to ask for some help, since I am in school and have normal homework.

Found that using [JSON-to-GO](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) helped solve future problems, will create the structs and other necessities based off a JSON content.

Comment: The second response json is not valid because 24 is not a string. Is this truly the response?

Comment: Yes it is, it is from the Openload API, you can read their documentation if you want. That is the exact response.

Comment: @Raymond No matter what the openload documentation may say, the second response in the question is not valid JSON. Please check that you posted an actual response to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    24:  {
      "id": 24,
      "remoteurl": "http://proof.ovh.net/files/100Mio.dat",
      "status": "new",
      "bytes_loaded": null,
      "bytes_total": null,
      "folderid": "4248",
      "added": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "last_update": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "extid": false,
      "url": false
    }
  }
}
```

Is not value JSON. You MUST mean the JSON i posted below, if you want to check yourself, copy your version of the JSON into any JSON validator;

https://jsonlint.com/

https://jsoneditoronline.org/

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Also view the thread linked below.. if the API truly is returning what you claim it returns then the API has a bug in it

[Why JSON allows only string to be a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304528/why-json-allows-only-string-to-be-a-key)

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    "24":  {
      "id": 24,
      "remoteurl": "http://proof.ovh.net/files/100Mio.dat",
      "status": "new",
      "bytes_loaded": null,
      "bytes_total": null,
      "folderid": "4248",
      "added": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "last_update": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "extid": false,
      "url": false
    }
  }
}
```

Here is some example code that uses a map to a struct what solves the dynamic response of the second response

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var res1 = `{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    "id": "24",
    "folderid": "4248"
  }
}`

var res2 = `{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    "24":  {
      "id": 24,
      "remoteurl": "http://proof.ovh.net/files/100Mio.dat",
      "status": "new",
      "bytes_loaded": null,
      "bytes_total": null,
      "folderid": "4248",
      "added": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "last_update": "2015-02-21 09:20:26",
      "extid": false,
      "url": false
    }
  }
}
`

type One struct {
    Status int    `json:"status"`
    Msg    string `json:"msg"`
    Result struct {
        ID       string `json:"id"`
        Folderid string `json:"folderid"`
    } `json:"result"`
}

type Two struct {
    Status int                  `json:"status"`
    Msg    string               `json:"msg"`
    Result map[string]innerData `json:"result"`
}

type innerData struct {
    ID          int         `json:"id"`
    Remoteurl   string      `json:"remoteurl"`
    Status      string      `json:"status"`
    BytesLoaded interface{} `json:"bytes_loaded"`
    BytesTotal  interface{} `json:"bytes_total"`
    Folderid    string      `json:"folderid"`
    Added       string      `json:"added"`
    LastUpdate  string      `json:"last_update"`
    Extid       bool        `json:"extid"`
    URL         bool        `json:"url"`
}

func main() {
    var one One
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(res1), &one)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var two Two
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(res2), &two)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //pretty print both strutures
    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(one, "", " ")
    fmt.Printf("%s \n\n", b)
    b, _ = json.MarshalIndent(two, "", " ")
    fmt.Printf("%s \n\n", b)

    // access data from two with id from one
    if dat, ok := two.Result[one.Result.ID]; ok {
        b, _ = json.MarshalIndent(dat, "", " ")
        fmt.Printf("inner data\n%s\n", b)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response if you look after the **** comment *** in the struct. You see I did have the : at the end. It just confused us all a little =D. Sorry about that, I edited it.