# How to call json if key is number

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have json data like this decode from API, i get with PHP

```
{
  "0": {
    "id_siswa": "14477",
    "rombel": "15",
    "nama_lengkap": "Cahyo"
  },
  "1": {
    "id_siswa": "14484",
    "rombel": "15",
    "nama_lengkap": "Bowo"
  },
  "2": {
    "id_siswa": "14485",
    "rombel": "13",
    "nama_lengkap": "Agus Sugiharto"
  }
}
```

but when i call

```
$data[0]->id_siswa
```

> Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

then i try to call like

```
$data->id_siswa
```

> error : Undefined property: stdClass::$id_siswa in

Comment: did you try $data["0"]->id_siswa ?

Comment: I think you should use `json_decode()` first

Comment: @executable `json_decode()` with `true` as 2nd param.

Comment: JSON keys are [always strings, not numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9304528/3345375). For example, `0` is a number and `"0"` is a string. Try using `$data["0"]` as Erwin Moller suggested above.

Comment: Using `$data[0]`, with a number as the index, is the way to access an element in an array. However, `$data` is not an array. That's why it's producing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode json to get array value. you will get `id_siswa` output.

```
$json = '{
    "0": {
      "id_siswa": "14477",
      "rombel": "15",
      "nama_lengkap": "Cahyo"
    },
    "1": {
      "id_siswa": "14484",
      "rombel": "15",
      "nama_lengkap": "Bowo"
    },
    "2": {
      "id_siswa": "14485",
      "rombel": "13",
      "nama_lengkap": "Agus Sugiharto"
    }
 }';
 echo "<pre>";
$result = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($result);
echo $result[0]['id_siswa'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_decode to convert json into array and get the corresponding values with $data[0]['id_siswa'] like this.

```
$result = json_decode($json,true);
```