# Why is an integer dictionary key retrieved as string from session?

Tags: python, django

In the code below, why is the `1` key of `people` dictionary retrieved as string in `session_retrieve` view? How can I keep the original (integer) type?

Also, why does the same not happen for the `45` value?

```
def session_add(request):
    people = {
        1: {
            'name': 'Tom',
            'age': 45,
        }   
    }
    request.session['people'] = people
    print(request.session['people'])
    # prints {1: {'name': 'Tom', 'age': 45}}
    return HttpResponse('added')

def session_retrieve(request):
    print(request.session['people'])
    # prints {'1': {'name': 'Tom', 'age': 45}}
    return HttpResponse('retrieved')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for JSON compatibility. Since keys are in essence attributes of a JavaScript object, they are strings. Fields can be any primitive or another object, so 45 remains a number.

[Why JSON allows only string to be a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304528/why-json-allows-only-string-to-be-a-key)

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is already mentioned in the documentation. Taking an example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization)

```
>>> # initial assignment
>>> request.session[0] = 'bar'
>>> # subsequent requests following serialization & deserialization
>>> # of session data
>>> request.session[0]  # KeyError
>>> request.session['0']
'bar'
```

*Also, why does the same not happen for the `45` value?*

JSON supports only string keys, but values can be anything.